# how to remove property duplicates inside Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new at `Neo4j` and i'm trying to learn it in order to start a project for my thesis, i spent a lot of time to manually reorganize a large dataset from xml to csv, then i imported a piece of this db inside Neo4j, i would avoid those duplicates but i canno't find a proper query, can you help me?

Thanks!
Please tell me if you need to know anything about this database or other stuff to undestand better the situation.

[image: Duplicates]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to ensure that the `dedicateePersonId` list has distinct values:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
UNWIND p.dedicateePersonId AS id
WITH p, COLLECT(DISTINCT id) AS ids
SET p.dedicateePersonId = ids
```

[UPDATE]

The above approach is sufficient if there was only one property that needs adjustment but very inappropriate (too complex and inefficient) for multiple properties.

Here is a much better approach (using the functions [apoc.create.setProperty](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/graph-updates/data-creation/) and [apoc.coll.toSet](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/data-structures/collection-list-functions/)) to update the values of any number of property keys. `keys` is assumed to be [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) containing the names of the properties to be updated.

```
MATCH (p:Person)
UNWIND $keys AS k
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(p, k, apoc.coll.toSet(p[k])) YIELD node
RETURN DISTINCT node
```

Comment: ok this is the problem, your query works in terms of a few properties, but i had to write a very long one and after two weeks of running i decided to stop because of not working. Here what i tried: https://textuploader.com/1qptp!
Any suggestions?

Comment: Using the same approach for many properties is *hugely* inefficient. See the update to my answer.

Comment: I've re-updated my answer again to show a nice succinct way to do what you want. You just need to pass a list of the names of the properties you want to be touched.

Comment: i made this: :param keys => ["artistPersonId","printerInfo"] (i choosed just a couple of properties to try) and then executed this query:
MATCH (o:Work)
UNWIND $keys AS k
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(o, k, apoc.coll.toSet([k])) YIELD node
RETURN DISTINCT node

i'm still waiting for it, btw can you tell me what the "n" in  "(n[k]))" stands for? 
Thanks a lot.

EDIT, black screen during the running, can you help? Is there anything i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Database failed to start: DB [database-9f155ccd-8c85-4fcd-8b84-5a9e9dfd070e] 'v3.5.14' exited with status 'KILLED'. Check the logs

Comment: I've corrected my answer. `n[k]` should have been `p[k]`. In your comment's query, replace `apoc.coll.toSet([k])` with `apoc.coll.toSet(o[k])`. I assume all these property values are lists. Try restarting the DB; if that does not help yu may have a corrupted DB.

Comment: thanks a lot! I tried with few nodes and it worked! Now i'm waiting to import the whole db to try your query in its entirety (hoping db didn't crash), btw, my import query takes more than 3 days to finish, do you know any smarter way to import the db maybe using APOC? this is my query:  https://textuploader.com/1cduz!

Comment: You should submit a new question for that.